# Help printing a barcode. Looking for best practice

Tags: javascript

I want to print a barcode that is generated by our system. I have a couple of concerns though and would like some input on the right way to do this if my solution is not right.

I have a link that the user can click to print this barcode. Once clicked, I thought it would be nice to use javascript to immediately being printing. I have this wourking so far. The first problem that I see is that when I print, I get "Page 1" at the top right. This throws off the measurement on the label I am printing to. The label has a maximum width of 2.63".

The second issue that I can see is that I am using a screen resolution of 1680x1050 to develop this. I am wondering if a user has a lower screen resolution if this will affect the height and width of the barcode when printed. I'm certain that it will but an not sure how to overcome this.

Can someone offer a better solution or tell me how I can overcome these issues?

Comment: Getting predictable positioning on print output from today's browsers is somewhere between difficult and impossible. I don't think any of them pay attention to page margin sizes and things like that.  You might be better off having your server make a PDF available.

Comment: @Pointy, I have to use a label printer so printing to a PDF isn't an option. A PDF would certainly be a much better and cleaner option, I agree.

Comment: well, good luck.  Browsers really suck at printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, barcodes are available as fonts. As long as you specify the font size in pixels it will be consistent.

You will likely need to experiment with a print.css file to get the results you desire.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Diodeus. I already have the font set, so you're right, I should be OK there. Does this dound like the best way to print the barcode?

Comment: Getting labels to line up with web printing is a trial and error process and will vary from browser to browser. It's OK if it's just for you, but if it's for a variety of clients it can be troublesome. You may want to consider a PDF generator if this doesn't work out.

Comment: OK Diodeus, thanks. It is for multiple users so I may have to come up with another solution because this isn't working out very well.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a couple of websites that generate position-specific information like this for printing, and they have generated PDF files for users to print.

PDF reading software is ubiquitous and you can ensure that the printed document appears exactly how you wish.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I have to use a label printer so printing to a PDF isn't an option. Diodeus mentioned that I should be OK if I have my fonts set, which I do. This should make the barcode the same exact size every time.